# Vector of derived class objects using shared_ptr

Tags: c++, derived-class

I have these classes:

```
class Element{
};
class Button : public Element{
};
class Label : public Element{
};
class Input : public Element{
};
```

And I want to be able to create a `void add(const Element & e)` function that would insert derived class object into a vector of shared_ptrs. 
The answers I've found suggested something like this:

```
vector<shared_ptr<CElement>>> vec;
vec.push_back(make_shared<DerivedClass>());
```

Which could work if I made an overloaded add function for each derived class, but that seems like a miserable solution.

So my question is: How do I insert a derived class object into a `vector<shared_ptr<CElement>>>` without knowing what derived class I'm trying to insert?

Comment: Typically, you'd use some "factory" object that built the correct type based on context and returned it

Comment: Why not just make the function `void add(shared_ptr<CElement> e)`?

Answer (score 3):

That's the beauty of casting. Your derived classes can be downcasted to the base class.

```
void add(std::shared_ptr<Element> ptr) {
    vec.push_back(ptr);
}

add(std::make_shared<Button>()); // std::shared_ptr<Button> casted to std::shared_ptr<Element>
```

Just don't forget to have a virtual destructor in your base class!

Comment: Cross out "if you want to have data in your derived classes". `Base* p = new Derived; delete p;` is always undefined behavior if `Base` does not have a virtual destructor.  (Not actually necessary if you *always* use `shared_ptr`, since it has a thing where `std::shared_ptr<Base> p = std::make_shared<Derived>();` actually does the correct thing even without virtual destructors -- but having the virtual destructor is still a good idea.)

Comment: Good point. Undefined behavior should be avoided even if it probably does the correct thing. I don't want the demons coming back through my nose again.

Comment: @N00byEdge you said like shared_ptr of type button is casted to element type when calling add function. The same casting should occur when calling push_back right? Why It haven't happened?

Comment: @N00byEdge Am sorry It happened. Hope for explanation you have done this.