# Unable to push an element of type child to a vector of type base using shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, c++20

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50165155), it appears the following code should work:

File Board.h:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Piece>> pawnRow;
for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
{
     pawnRow.push_back(std::make_shared<Pawn>());
}
```

For reference Pawn.h:

```
#include "Piece.h"

class Pawn : Piece
{};
```

Instead I'm getting: `error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Piece> >::push_back(std::shared_ptr<Pawn>)'`

What am I missing here? My ultimate goal is to have a vector of "pieces" that I can call functions like `possibleMoveLocations()` that will call the overloaded function in the child class.

Using C++20, gcc version 11.2.0 (MSYS2), Windows 11

Comment: `Pawn` inherits _privately_ from `Piece`, which means that nobody else (in particular, `shared_ptr`) knows this. You meant to inherit _publicly_.

Comment: That looks like an answer to me.

Comment: Yup! Thank you so much @Barry!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Barry's comment, I had to inherit `Piece` publicly like so:

```
#include "Piece.h"

class Pawn : public Piece
{};
```

The code compiled just fine thereafter!

Comment: This is the way.